# Stuck in a storm. Where is Grandpa?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

When Grandpa called, he sounded very unhappy.

"I am supposed to be in Paris but here I am stuck in a storm!", he grumbled.

"I am in the middle of nowhere. At the end of the line, front of the lobby, standing for hours. Trying to get a room for the night!"

"What city are you in Grandpa?" I asked

Then the cell connection died.

What city was Grandpa in? Why?

Comment: Grandpa needs to learn to be a bit less cryptic if he expects a timely rescue.  Time and a place, gramps...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think Grandpa might be stuck in:

> **Helsinki**, Finland.

The wording of the puzzle suggests that Grandpa is stranded at an intermediate **airport** whilst attempting to travel to Paris as a result of bad weather ('stuck in a storm... trying to get a room for the night...'), but some of his words here have an additional hidden significance:

> If we take:
>
>  - the *middle* of NOW**H**ERE,
>  - the *end* of LIN**E**, and
>  - the *front* of **L**OBBY
>
>  ...these 3 letters spell **HEL**, which is the standard 3-letter IATA code for [Helsinki-Vantaa Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki_Airport).

Here's hoping that Grandpa's cell is a:

> [Nokia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia) - as then at least he's in the right country to find a compatible charger easily!

Comment: Another superb solve @Stiv. Well at least took you a few minutes this time. Not seconds like you normally do.

Comment: Annoyingly had this but thought "Standing for hours" signified another "h" and was trying to make something like Helhoek work. Will teach me to overthink things, well done.

Comment: @hexomino Thanks. I went through a very similar train of thought, trying to spell out the whole word. It was only when I thought to interpret what I had in the context of the puzzle's setting that I realised what I had might actually be sufficient...

Comment: He's in Hohhot (HET) if he's at "the front of _the lobby_". +1 for your answer, -1 for the question.

Comment: Got the TLA immediately but didn't spot how to interpret it. Thanks!